# Which algebraic structure is like a magma augmented with an operation which is an anti-function?

Tags: trees, universal-algebra, programming

Is there any structure similar to a free magma, including an operation which splits, or undoes, the binary operation?

```
A set S together with two operations (S, •, ~)

• : S × S → S
~ : S → S × S

Where ⋅(∼(x)) = x
```

Background: 
If free magmas abstractly describe binary tree structures, they don't provide a mechanism to opaquely decompose nodes for examination. Which structure does?

Comment: Do you want the two operations to interact in any way? E.g. $\cdot(\sim(x))=x$?

Comment: Only very vaguely related but perhaps interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalgebra

Comment: @NoahSchweber yeah, ⋅(∼(x)) = x should hold. But ~ could also be split into two functions: ~L ~R, where ⋅(~L(x), ~R(x)) = x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the Jónsson-Tarski algebras. Given a set $X$ together with a bijection $m:X\times X\to X$, we have the reverse map $X\to X\times X$ and the left and right components can be given by $\ell:X\to X$ and $r:X\to X$. In other words it satisfies the identities:

$m(r(x),\ell(x))=x$, $r(m(x,y))=x$, and $\ell(m(x,y))=y$.

Some interesting facts about Jónsson-Tarski algebras include:

1. The only finite Jónsson-Tarski algebra is trivial,
2. the free Jónsson-Tarski algebra on $n$ generators is isomorphic to the free Jónsson-Tarski algebra on $m$ generators, and
3. the automorphism group of the finitely generated free Jónsson-Tarski algebra is Thompson's group $V$.

Comment: is there such a thing as a co-magma (a magma with the arrows reversed for •)? Could a Jónsson-Tarski algebra then be viewed as a bi-magma (comagma + magma).

Comment: That's an interesting question. Unfortunately, I do not know enough about co-algebra to have an answer.